# Writing a fixed length buffer with an offset

Tags: c++, buffer

I am trying to write a buffer with a fixed length and correctly offset it so that it goes through the whole buffer but I can't figure out how to do the offset.

```
int width = 512;
int height = 512;
int count = 304;
size_t size = width * height * 2 * count; // buffer size
char * buffer = new char[size];
```

Now I want to write the same size buffer 304 times (count = 304)

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    write(fd, buffer, size/count);
}
```

This sends the correctly sized buffer but it sends the same data each time. How do I get  it to go through the buffer and send the next chunk of data till the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you want to use the count for both iterating and controlling the size, you cannot correctly do that using your loop because the write call may in fact send out less than you asked.  If you wish to limit the write to the number of bytes in count, you need to track the bytes written.

```
char* p = buffer;
int n;
while (size > 0){
   n = write(fd, p, size/count);
   if (n < 0) {
      // handle error as appropriate to your needs
   }
   size -= n;
   p += n;  
}
```

While ignoring the return value of write often works, particularly for files, it often will return less than requested over socket descriptors.

Check the "return value" section of the page shown in man 2 write for reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    write(fd, &buffer[size/count * i], size/count);
}
```

where `&buffer[size/count * i]` means take the address of the `i`th `size/count`-sized block in `buffer`.

Although thinking about this a bit more, the point is kind of moot. The output will receive the same as it would with `write(fd, buffer, size);` For testing I'd put some sort of marker between the blocks and remove it later after I knew the code worked. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    write(fd, &buffer[size/count * i], size/count);
    write(fd, "BLOCK", 5);// remove after testing
}
```

Comment: So I am actually reading in a file and then doing this write based off of that data. When I do a diff on the two files they are different so something is still off

Comment: @user1984300 Definitely leave the `write(fd, "BLOCK", 5);` out in the diff case. That extra BLOCK tag should make it easier to use the ol' mark 1 eyeball to compare the source vs the output block by block to see where the  differences are, but utterly screws diff. You may want to ask new question with the reading code, your current writing code, and a little `main` function to see if there's something else missing in there. Maybe a data alignment snafu or something, but no way for me to tell without more info.

Comment: yeah i did the diff without the write block. I'm doing a fopen, reading in a file, and then writing it. But I need to write it in 304 blocks in order which is why I am using the for loop

Comment: @user1984300 Could there be header or control information in the input file that your `size_t size = width * height * 2 * count;` calculation is leaving out? Can't do much for you without more information.

Comment: Hmm okay. I can ask another question with more information if that could help you understand the situation better

Answer (score -1):

```
hFileIpAddress = CreateFile(szIpAddFilePath,GENERIC_WRITE|GENERIC_READ,NULL,NULL,OPEN_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);

for (int i = 0 i<304 ; i++)
{
    dwCurrentPtr = SetFilePointer(hFileIpAddress, 0, NULL, FILE_CURRENT); // it return current offset that you can use while reading.
    WriteFile(hFileIpAddress,szIpAddress,sizeof buffer,&dwBytesWritten,NULL);
}
```

Comment: Before writing you can get offset "dwCurrentPtr" and it can be use if you want to read specific entry while reading.

Comment: Recommend trying to keep the answers generic. Nothing in OPs question says they are compiling for Win32